# Calling an overloaded function in recursive function in Swift

Tags: swift, overloading, extension-methods

I was doing an online exercise for learing Swift. The following code is a test case singled out to show the issue with calling an overloaded version of a function that is called in a recursive situation.

```
import Foundation

//Solution goes in Sources
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func accumulate (_ acc: (Element) throws -> Element) rethrows -> [Element] {
        var newArray : [Element]?
        
        try self.forEach{try newArray?.append(acc($0))}
        
        return newArray!
    }
    func accumulate (_ acc: (Element) throws -> [Element]) rethrows -> [[Element]] {
        var newArray : [[Element]]?
        
        try self.forEach{try newArray?.append(acc($0))}
        
        return newArray!
    }
}
let input =   ["a", "b", "c"]
let expected = [
    ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
] // The expected result of the statement on the bottom of this code
func recurse(_ input: String) -> [String] {
    func appendTo(_ innerInput: String) -> String {
        return input+innerInput
    }
    let result = ["1", "2", "3"].accumulate(appendTo)
    print("3")
    return result
}
let result = input.accumulate(recurse)
```

When run, the compiler didn't complain, but the runtime showed the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007fa0d799c920 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 69
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007fa0d78aaa06 <unavailable> + 3279366
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007fa0d78aad85 <unavailable> + 3280261
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007fa0d76d2810 _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 19
4    main                               0x000055df0a54ef3a <unavailable> + 7994
5    main                               0x000055df0a54e63e <unavailable> + 5694
6    libc.so.6                          0x00007fa0d6052ab0 __libc_start_main + 231
7    main                               0x000055df0a54e09a <unavailable> + 4250
exited, illegal instruction
```

Please kindly tell me what wrong there is with my code and explain the reason.

Thank you very much!

Comment: newArray is nil and then you force unwrap it with !

Comment: `var newArray : [Element] = []`, but I don't understand what you're doing here and if optional array is required for you. Anyway, your code will never work unless you set `newArray` to something before you append to it and then force unwrap it

Comment: Keep in mind that any time you put `!` after an optional variable, you're telling the code to crash if it's nil.  Whenever you type that, think about whether crashing is what you want.

Comment: Especially if the variable is an optional, initialised as nil, and never modified, so it stays nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing has nothing to do with overloading per se. You just have  `newArray = nil` in every variant that you try to force unwrap, for example:

```
func accumulate (_ acc: (Element) throws -> Element) rethrows -> [Element] {
    var newArray : [Element]? // here, newArray = nil
    
    // newArray is still nil, and newArray?.append does nothing
    try self.forEach{try newArray?.append(acc($0))}
    
    // new array is still nil, and you force unwrap nil, hence Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    return newArray!
}
```

To fix that you can just assign some value to `newArray` in the beginning:

```
var newArray : [Element] = []
```

If you're still learning swift, I would suggest to adopt the "never force unwrap (unless completely necessary)" rule. Additionally, I would suggest to never force cast as well. You can almost always rewrite your code without force unwrap/cast.

Comment: var newArray = [Element]()

Comment: @gnasher729 that's just a matter of style, I prefer mine over yours. I should also add that relying too heavily on type inference can cause slower build times and hurt readability, though in your example it might not be the case.

Comment: Thank you, @MANIAK_dobrii. I should have remembered to provide an empty shoebox after I created the label.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to note:

1. The most immediate problem here is that you're force unwrapping `newArray`, which is an optional var that you initialize with nil, but never assign a non-nil value.
2. You have to overloads `accumulate`, but they can be merged with a generic.
3. Your `accumulate` is actually `map`. The term "accumulate" is usually associated with the `reduce`/`fold` operation.
4. Your `appendTo(_:)` function is wonky.

   1. According to Swift's naming conventions, it should be `append(to:)`. But that doesn't make sense, because the arg isn't what's being *appended to*, it's what's being *appended*. I would suggest naming it simply `append(_:)`.
   2. It doesn't add much value over just using the `+` operator directly
5. Your `recurse` function doesn't ever actually recurse.

Here's how I would write this:

```
import Foundation

//Solution goes in Sources
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func myMap<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T] {
        var newArray = [T]()
        newArray.reserveCapacity(self.count)
        
        for element in self { 
            try newArray.append(transform(element))
        }
        
        return newArray
    }
}

let input = ["a", "b", "c"]
let expected = [
    ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"],
]

func nameMeBetter(_ input: String) -> [String] {
    return ["1", "2", "3"].myMap { input + $0 }
}

let result = input.myMap(nameMeBetter)
print(result)
```

Since `myMap(_:)` is just the same as the built in `Sequence.map(_:)`, we can use that directly.

All this code boils down to simply:

```
let input = ["a", "b", "c"]
let expected = [
    ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"],
]

let result = input.map { char in
    ["1", "2", "3"].map { digit in
        char + digit
    }
}
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, for your help. You idea of making the method generic is very nice. But I'm afraid, we can't change the test code under the `Array extension` block. That test code is a test case exerpted from the testsuite for the `Array extension` provided on the online exercise website. Anyway, your solution is very good in the particular case of the question in this post.

Comment: @MichaelMay I suppose your instructure was trying to avoid introducing generics to early. Did they also suggest that optional to be there? it's weird.

Comment: No, the online exercise website doesn't provide instructions if I don't request mentor help. For this exercise, I didn't. I added the Optional myself. Sorry, I can't remember why I chose to use Optional. Thank you for your help.